# R programming: which(colnames(df) == "thecolumnname") is not working inside a function?

Tags: r, function

I have a function:

```
findcolnumber <- function(df, thecolumnname){
which(colnames(df) == "thecolumnname")
}
```

And I would like to be able to find the column number by giving the 2 arguments to the function.

Example arguments: data, columnX

```
which(colnames(data) == "columnX")    #This works properly

findcolnumber(data, columnX)    #This does not work
```

The function that I created does not work.  Do you know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function isn't working because while the column name must be quoted (which you did), the argument and the quoted column name should be the other way around.  That problem is fixed at the bottom of this answer.

First though, I'd like to point out that this is a situation where `deparse` and `substitute` come in very handy. Together, they eliminate the need to quote your function argument(s). Here's an example:

```
> findcolnumber <- function(df, thecolumnname){
      which(colnames(df) == deparse(substitute(thecolumnname)))
  }

> x <- data.frame(col1 = 1:4, col2 = 3:6, col3 = letters[1:4])

> findcolnumber(x, col1)
[1] 1
> findcolnumber(x, col2)
[1] 2
> findcolnumber(x, col3)
[1] 3
```

---

Now, if you want to do it without deparse and substitute, you could do the following.  Notice that you'll need to quote the column name in the function call.  That's why `deparse(substitute(...))` is nice.

```
> findcolnumber <- function(df, thecolumnname){
      which(colnames(df) == thecolumnname)
  }
> findcolnumber(x, "col3")
[1] 3
```

Comment: +1 I always end up feeding column names to my functions with quotes around them.  Nice to learn about `deparse` and `substitute`.

Comment: They are very nice when creating custom functions.

Comment: They are nice until you want to pass a variable to the function. Then things get messy. I can't believe now may times i've seen people try `dataframe$variable` where `variable=="columnname"` or try to use variables with column names in the `aes()` part of a `ggplot` function. Both have alternative interfaces for those cases; but if you ask me, it's much more flexible to pass character values.

Comment: Good points.  In the case of passing a variable to a function, I'd probably use `get()`.  But I agree that it's probably more flexible to just quote the character values. Most times, I just like to write general functions that anyone can easily use.